# Web Service callbacks with .net framework 1.1

Tags: web-services, notifications

I am having a .net windows application developed with 1.1 framework and this app needs to be notified about an event when that occurs. I am trying to use webservice callbacks by asynchronously calling the service. But the examples that I get are for framework 2.0 alone and does not work for 1.1 framework.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the application from 1.1 to 2.0.. better version with better functionalities. Jst open your existing application with 2.0 and it will automatically convert your 1.1 into 2.0.. Let me know if you have already tried this one..

Comment: My application is very huge and converting to 2.0 is not feasible as of now.